# Write permissions to multiple users on same directory in ProFTPD

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, user-permissions

I am quite new to Webmin and ProFTPD and I am trying to give multiple users access on a public_html, both users are in same group:

siteowner:x:504:504::/home/thepclincom
secuser.thepnlincom:x:510:504::/home/thepclincom/public_html

Site's ownership is set to:

siteowner siteowner

Please suggest me how would I give these both users write access to public_html?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest - create another group with all the users needing write access

make the directory group writable

and change the group ownership of the dir to the newly created group

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but making directory group writable would change permissions to 775, while public_html works on 750. So, it is out of picture as I tried it as well. Is there any way purely through ProFTPD config or command?